# Automatically build android APK packages using Kivy and buildozer in .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: docker, kivy, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, buildozer

I want to use [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/#create-a-gitlab-ciyml-file) to automatically build android packages using [Kivy's buildozer](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html) within the [Python 3.9 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to be short and specific and provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have now discovered that also a [docker image](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer#buildozer-docker-image) exists for `buildozer`!

Here are the steps that worked for me under Windows 10 inspired by [this](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/985#issuecomment-541328985) answer:

**Installation steps**

Clone repo:

`$ git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer`

Go to folder:

`$ cd buildozer`

Remove entrypoint line `ENTRYPOINT ["buildozer"]` from `Dockerfile` and build docker image (the entry point prevents gitlabs runner to open a shell via `sh`):

`$ docker build --tag=buildozer .`

Go to project folder with kivy(md) app code and run:

`$ docker run --volume ${pwd}:/home/user/hostcwd buildozer buildozer init`

Edit buildozer.spec file:

`android.accept_sdk_license = True` and add python package requirements as well as `pillow`.

Build first apk file and install all requirements within container
(if you have trouble running this command and tried several other approaches before,
make sure to delete the .buildozer and bin folders before):

`$ docker run --volume ${pwd}:/home/user/hostcwd buildozer buildozer android debug`

Check the containers:

`$ docker ps -a`

Commit the container where the successful build happened in order
to save the added installation files for later builds:

`$ docker commit sharp_nightingale registry.gitlab.com/my_user/my_repo:latest`

Login to registry:

`$ docker login registry.gitlab.com`

Push container to registry:

`$ docker push registry.gitlab.com/my_user/my_repo`

**Usage of container from registry**

```yaml
image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

run-buildozer:
  script:
    - buildozer android debug
  only:
    - main
```

It took me a while so it hopefully helps someone else!